# How to create new CustomTypes and CustomField from json file?

Tags: commercetools

I have a question, I wanna to extend my categories with CustomType and CustomFields.

I have my json files that lied in `resource/migrate` folder.

I have json file like that:

```
{
  "key": "category",
  "name": {
    "en": "CategoryNewFields"
  },
  "resourceTypeIds": ["category"],
  "fieldDefinitions": [
    {
      "name": "test",
      "type": { "name": "String" },
      "required": true,
      "label": {
        "en": "test"
      },
      "inputHint": "SingleLine"
    },
    {
      "name": "test1",
      "type": { "name": "String" },
      "required": false,
      "label": {
        "en": "test1"
      },
      "inputHint": "SingleLine"
    },
    {
      "name": "test2",
      "type": { "name": "Boolean" },
      "required": true,
      "label": {
        "en": "test2"
      },
      "inputHint": "SingleLine"
    }
  ]
}
```

I don't wanna implementation of extend CT structure through the code. I wanna do it like a flyway migration. I mean, I named file like this `V1_category_custom_field` and it migrates to CT and creates in Categories new custom fields.

Is it possible to implement it with some gradle plugin or gradle task? CommerceTools has service where I can generate gradle task or staff like that or maybe it has some examples how it can be done with gradle?

And additional question It is possible to update CustomType type from json using  sync API?

Answer (score 1):

Thanks for sharing your question!

While we do not have any examples or prebuilt services for gradle task I do have some recommendations that should be helpful.

We have a tool called impex that supports category updates from a CSV file or JSON. You can log in with you commercetools credentials and upload using the externalId as the reference to the category.

https://impex.commercetools.com/commands/category-import

You will need to verify that is process will work with custom types and custom fields.

The best recommendation I can make is to write some sort of script that would handle this process for you. The script would receive the json file, create the custom type through the API and then update the category accordingly.

Is this information helpful? Please let us know if you have any additional questions.